Using the platform_release environment marker
I'm developing a Python package that has an optional dependency that is incompatible with certain versions of macOS.
Since the dependency is optional, I want my (wheel-based) package installation to succeed even on systems that have the incompatible OS.
To achieve this, I have the following in my requirements list:
'scipy >=1.7, <2; platform_release >= "21.0.0"'

This works fine for most circumstances. However, some people are using tools like Bazel for installation. Bazel is using a method in pkg_resources/_vendor/packaging/markers.py for evaluating the markers. This raises an InvalidVersion exception on some systems because the platform_release marker evaluates to a version string that is not PEP 440 compliant.
For example, on a Linux box the value of platform_release may be something like 6.5.0-172-generic.
Because the markers don't always evaluate properly, and because the values come from Python's own platform module, this seems like an oversight in how Bazel is designed, or perhaps even how pkg_resources is designed.
Searches online reveal several threads where Pypa maintainers say this is the correct behavior.
How do I work around this problem? As a package maintainer, can I "canonicalize" the platform_release marker or override the markers at runtime to permit installation, for example? Ostensibly this is not possible because there is no way to run pre-install scripts when installing a wheel!

You said "wheel-based" package installation but you also talk about Bazel. A wheel installation will not invoke a build system at all, it is mostly just unzipping an archive. Your packaging should faithfully reproduce the requirement line with environment marker directly into the wheel metadata, and it should not evaluate those markers. Bazel will only be used for a source install, or to create the wheel in the first place. So, could you clarify on that point - "some people" are using tools like Bazel - which people? Your users will be installing from wheel(s) right?

My users are the ones using Bazel and are installing my package as a wheel. The markers for my wheel's dependencies are what appear to be causing the issue.

Okay, thanks for clarifying. PEP 508 has this to say about the situation: The <version_cmp> operators use the PEP 440 version comparison rules when those are defined (that is when both sides have a valid version specifier). If there is no defined PEP 440 behaviour and the operator exists in Python, then the operator falls back to the Python behaviour. So it sounds as though using a string comparison is correct here, the InvalidVersion exception should be handled and fall back to str.__ge__.

Could you include some references for those "threads where the PyPA maintainers insist this is the correct behavior"?

Thanks for the comment, I only gave PEP 508 a quick read and must have missed that.
I'll try to dig up the threads again. FWIW, I do agree with the maintainers; but given that the markers don't necessarily comply with PEP 440, I feel like there should be some way to address this somehow (maybe via Bazel confg?)

Your only options may be to use a bunch of == on platform_release instead of >=. The client can override their platform_release, of course, but as the package maintainer you can't do that for them.

Thanks for the help @wim! I may try that.
